How find distribution? Discrete X with numbers from 0 to 50
I'm looking to find a distribution to make a model for my variable...
I have variable X which is "Number of articles published by researchers by the end of the PhD"
it is a discrete variable in this case assumes values (in my database) between 0 and 50...
I'm having a hard time finding a model because discrete distributions always assume values of failure and success (bernoulli) like binomial, geometric, hyper...
And in my case the variable takes integer values from 0 to 50.
There is no "success" just a number of articles published by researchers
Should I treat as continuous? I don't think it makes sense because there is no way to publish 0.3 articles
Any ideia?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution would be my first thought. It probably doesn't quite work because it makes some strict assumptions about how the event in question (i.e. article publication) happens. But it might be a good place to start.

That being said, what's wrong with considering a day that has a publication as a success and a day that doesn't have a publication a failure, and go binomial?
